# How to rename the pictures hyperlinked in Excel by the content in column

Tags: excel, image, vba, hyperlink

I have a excel list with a lot of strings, eg. "$FB9275" in column A and many pictures hyperlinked in column B are stored in the folder with strange name, eg."4e584a1c6911".And I want to rename the pictures hyperlinked in column B by the content in column A.
I'm a freshman, thank you!
[sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QurgW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add to your project the reference to "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" library in order to exploit `FileSystemObject` object

then use this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim currenthWbPath As String, oldName As String
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim file As file
    Dim hyp As Hyperlink

    With ActiveWorkbook  '<--| refer to currently active workbook
        currenthWbPath = .Path '<--| store its full path
        With .Worksheets("pics") '<--| refer to its "pics" worksheet (change it as per your needs)
            For Each cell In .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants) '<--| loop through referenced sheet column "B" cells with values in it
                If cell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then '< if current cell contains a hyperlink
                    Set hyp = cell.Hyperlinks.Item(1) '<-- stote the first hyperlink object associated to the cell
                    If fso.FileExists(currenthWbPath & "\" & hyp.Address) Then '<--| if the hyperlink leads to an existent file
                        Set file = fso.GetFile(currenthWbPath & "\" & hyp.Address) '<--| get the file corresponding to hyperlink
                        oldName = file.name '<-- store old name
                        file.name = cell.Offset(, -1) & "." & fso.GetExtensionName(file.Path)  '<--| rename the file
                        hyp.Address = Replace(hyp.Address, oldName, file.name)  '<--| refresh hyperlink address
                        hyp.TextToDisplay = cell.Hyperlinks.Item(1).Address '<--| refresh hyperlink text to display
                    Else
                        ' code to deal with invalid hyperlinks
                    End If
                End If
            Next cell
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @yuyu: did you get through it?

Comment: There comes an error！Array Index Out Of Bounds! you can follow link：http://pan.baidu.com/s/1i5qa2Mh key：1xra

Comment: which line throws that error? did it work before you changed anything?

Comment: I changed nothing! you can follow my link above to check it. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again.Why it just deal with ONLY one row when comes  to CHINESE Strings?It worked every row when dealing with ENGLISH strings.Don't understand.

Comment: Unfortunately I never dealt with chinese characthers, so I can't help you along that way. A blind shot could be that all values from the 2nd row on are a formula result instead of "constant" values. Can you confirm it?

Comment: What a pity! I'm a fresh man so I can't follow you.I'll try myself.Thank you!

Comment: Try this: just after "For Each cell In .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeConstants)" place "MsgBox . Address" and see how many/which cells has been _captured_